# Javascript function construct

Tags: javascript, syntax

What does this construct mean?

```
var digits = [1, 2, 3];

(function fetchData(name){
 //body
})(digits.shift());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax is used to prevent identifiers from leaking into the containing namespace.

After that code, if you attempt to call `fetchData(name)` you will find that `fetchData` is undefined, thanks to the () wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

which construct?

I can explain what's happening, if that will help:

(in the order of execution)

1. array gets created and assigned the name of "digits"
2. the first element of "digits" gets removed from the array - so the length of the array gets reduced
3. that value that got removed gets passed as an argument into the function fetchData() as the variable "name"

Answer (score 1):

Declare a function and call it.

Click on this http://jsfiddle.net/TC8K6/ you will see a alert of the parameter passed to the function.